# How to call native API of a dll whose source files are not present using java

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a C++ dll without the source codes. I have to use java to call the API of the dll and have full documentation for the dll.

Can somebody please tell me how to do it using JNI?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp)!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, you can recreate the entire interface for the DLL in Java and use JNA to access it without writing any native code, or create a JNI wrapper for the DLL in C/C++ and basically translate the native function calls and returns to something Java can understand.  This usually involves type translations from things like jstring <=> char * and struct xyz <=> jobject xzy.  The JNI code will run a little faster than JNA but other than that it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Can you please explain it more. If i use the JNi approach, when i write a wrapper in C, do i need to compile it with the dll? I don't have access to the source files for the dll

Comment: If you have a static library, you can statically link a JNI DLL with all the code needed in one file.  If all you have is a DLL, then you will end up with 2 DLL files.  The JNI DLL will be placed in your java.library.path and your Proprietary DLL will need to be somewhere in the systems DLL library path.